# Get an entire row from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'll explain my issue : I have a DataGrid, filled from a DataSet who contains information from a Project 2010 server. I'd like to select one or multiples rows from my DataGrid, and when the user clicks a button, those rows will be deleted from the original DataGrid, and sent to a second one.

I've searched a lot, but I can't figure how to do this ! Perhaps using DataGrids isn't a good idea or idk, but I'm pretty new to WPF and it seemed the best way to do this to me !

So if you could give me a hint to move data from a DataGrid to another, or any other method to do this, it'd be really great !

Answer (score 0):

Yeah dealing with datagrid can be sometimes painful at the beginning but I still prefer using it.

Deleting a single row is not a hard task, I usually delete from the database then just reload the datagrid again, maybe this will help you:

Add this to the datagrid in xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="dataGrid1_PreviewDeleteCommandHandler" Name="dataGrid1" />
```

Then create the method in code to be something like this:

```
private void dataGrid1_PreviewDeleteCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == DataGrid.DeleteCommand)
    {
        //Get the row data before deleting 
        DataGridRow selectedRow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex);
        DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)selectedRow.Item;

        // First cell in the row is usually the ID of the row (you can modify that in your database)
        string recNoToDelete = rv.Row[0].ToString();
        if (recNoToDelete == "")
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            return;
        }
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete this row?","", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {

            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand("", Conn);

            // Delete
            Comm = new SqlCommand("", Conn);
            Comm.CommandText = "Delete from Table where field=@field";
            Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", recNoToDelete);
            Conn.Open();
            Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Conn.Close();

            // Reload all the data again in the datagrid after deletion of that record
            ReloadData();
            }
            else
            {
                //record is not valid or has been deleted or manipulated
                //cancel the delete operation
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

However, this will work when the user is clicking on the row and pressing "Delete" key. As for deleting multiple columns I still didn't figure that out, but when I do I'll update the answer.

I hope this could help you start at least.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps my explanation of the problem was bad. I don't want to delete anything from the DB. In fact, the selected rows will disappear from the first Datagrid, and will be put into another one. I don't know if it's possible, or if I need to use something else than Datagrids, like I said I'm rather new to WPF.

And excuse me if my question wasn't comprehensible, my english isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

On how to delete multiple rows;

First make selection mode to extended on dataGrid

```
SelectionMode="Extended"
```

Then the selectedItems property will return a list of selected objects (depends on what you bind to DataGrid)

Iterate the list and delete the items from database and fresh.
eg:

```
 For Each item As <object> In Me.MyDataGrid.SelectedItems
     --delete record--
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my answer : working with DataGrid was the bad way, and I must work with the DataSet directly, instead !